# Trying to deploy to appfog anchorcms

Tags: php, json, terminal, appfog

I have just installed the command line tool for appfog and logged in, in the instructions it says `run af update app` Now I am trying to setup [anchorcms][1] do I run af update anchor (when I am in the anchor directory or in its parent directory) because when I do so I get the following error. Also one of the first getting started commands is `target [url]` do I run that with the square brackets? Also do I write af before that, and do I put my app fog url inside the square brackets.

If at all, you could help me through the steps of deploying anchorcms to appfog, that would be amazing.

```
Error (JSON 404): Not Found
```

**The output i get for af apps**

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ af apps

+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| Application | #  | Health  | URLS                      | Services | In     |
+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| anchortuts  | 1  | RUNNING | anchortuts.ap01.aws.af.cm |          | ap-aws |
+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+


  [1]: http://anchorcms.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

No do not run the command with square brackets.

You only need to set the target once to https://api.appfog.com

```
af target https://api.appfog.com
```

Then login with"

```
af login email@example.com
```

The first time an app is uploaded to AppFog you use the `push` command. From then on you use the `update` command.

Example:

From the app's root folder create a new AppFog app named mycmsapp. The command will lead you through a set of questions.

```
af push mycmsapp
```

Later when you have made changes to your app and are ready to publish them:

```
af update mycmsapp
```

Comment: Do I set my target to my subdomain I created or to api.appfog.com?

Comment: Target is set to only https://api.appfog.com. The target is what the af tool uses to talk to AppFog. It does not relate to your app. Set it only once and forget it.

Comment: Ok I followed your instructions and used push mycms app inside of my anchor folder at this link http://anchorcms.hp.af.cm/ I am getting a 404 not found.

Comment: try running `af apps` to make sure that domain is mapped to your app and the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

The `af` CLI tool doesn't make this very clear, but the `af target` command is only used for setting the API URL.

If you want to use a custom domain for your app, you need to use the `af map <app name> appurl.com` command.

In this situation:

```
+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| Application | #  | Health  | URLS                      | Services | In     |
+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| anchortuts  | 1  | RUNNING | anchortuts.ap01.aws.af.cm |          | ap-aws |
+-------------+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------+
```

You would run this command to set a target URL:

```
af map anchortuts www.anchortuts.com
```

You will need to update the DNS for your domain to add a CNAME record pointing to `cname01.ap01.aws.af.cm`. This value will change according to which infrastructure you're using. The full details are available in the AppFog documentation for [custom domain names](https://docs.appfog.com/customize/custom-domain-names).

You may also use the AppFog [web console](http://console.appfog.com) for mapping your domains.